# how to make button works like carousel-indicators

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

hi i have carousel on my page and i'm adding buttons into the sliders and i want to make that buttons on click change to next slide like the carousel-indicators but i don't know how to do it so it will be nice if some one explained to me how to ... here's my carousel code

```html
<section id="slide" class="text-center">
       <div class="container">
           <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
               <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                   <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                   <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                   <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
               </ol>
               <div class="carousel-inner">
                   <div class="item active">
                       <h1>Head Line</h1>
                       <p>Paragraph</p>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"> button </button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="item">
                       <h1>Head Line 2</h1>
                       <p>Paragraph 2</p>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">button2</button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="item">
                       <h1>Head Line 3</h1>
                       <p>Paragraph 3</p>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">button3</button>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
         </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```html
<section id="slide" class="text-center">
       <div class="container">
           <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
               <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                   <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                   <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                   <li data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
               </ol>
               <div class="carousel-inner">
                   <div class="item active">
                       <h1>Head Line</h1>
                       <p>Paragraph</p>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="1"> button </button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="item">
                       <h1>Head Line 2</h1>
                       <p>Paragraph 2</p>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="2">button2</button>
                   </div>
                   <div class="item">
                       <h1>Head Line 3</h1>
                       <p>Paragraph 3</p>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-target="#mycarousel" data-slide-to="0">button3</button>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
         </section>
```